# AFTER upgrade from Spring boot 1.2 to 1.5.2, FileNotFoundException during Tomcat 8.5 Startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat8.5

I **upgraded** Spring **Boot** from 1.2.0 to **1.5.2**.

**After** that upgrade, Tomcat **8.5** is throwing **FileNotFoundException** during **startup**.

Below is **one of** those exceptions, It is throwing **more than ~10 similar** exceptions.

I have no idea about the **purpose** of these jars, In other words, I didn't add `<dependency>` for these jars in **pom.xml.**

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
Apr 06, 2017 3:53:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan
WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/myname/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.1.7/jaxws-api.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\myname\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\ws\jaxws-rt\2.1.7\jaxws-api.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:48)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:338)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:288)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @AntonNovopashin, Thanks for the response, I solved this error and documented the solution as answer.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**RootCause:**

As per **[Tomcat Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp)**, Servlet 3.0 specification requires Jar scanning during server startup.

Tomcat is using org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.[StandardJarScanner](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/scan/StandardJarScanner.html) for this purpose.

From the javadoc of **StandardJarScanner**.

> The default JarScanner implementation **scans the WEB-INF/lib** directory
> followed by the provided classloader and then works up the classloader
> hierarchy. This implementation is sufficient to **meet the requirements
> of the Servlet 3.0 specification** as well as to provide a number of
> Tomcat specific extensions. The extensions are:
>
> - Scanning the classloader hierarchy (enabled by default) Testing all files to see if they are JARs (disabled by default)
> - Testing all directories to see if they are exploded JARs (disabled by default)
> - All of the extensions **may be controlled via configuration**.

**Solution1: Spring Boot specific.**

We can **disable** this jar scanning.

I disabled it by adding below property in application-xxx.properties file. This property is [**Spring Boot specific**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

```
# Comma-separated list of additional patterns that match jars to ignore for TLD scanning.    
server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=*.jar
```

You can find **similar properties from Tomcat** [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/systemprops.html#JAR_Scanning).

These properties can be used to configure **traditional** tomcat (**non**-spring boot) applications.

**Solution2: Spring specific**

You can disable the JarScanner for **manifest** files as below.

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
  return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    @Override
    protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
      ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner()).setScanManifest(false);
    }
  };
}
```

**Solution3 : Traditional Standalone Tomcat:**

```
<Context>
  ...
  <JarScanner scanManifest="false"/>
  ...
</Context>
```

Refer : [**The Jar Scanner Component**](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/jar-scanner.html).

Comment: But since those are part of the JDK why is it scanning the maven repo for them?
Disable works but shouldn't it not search those jar in their ?

Comment: Great. Helped me identify issue. In my case I filtered the specific jars as a comma separated list:   server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=oraclepki.jar,osdt_core.jar,osdt_cert.jar

Comment: Are those solution good if you have a tag library in your JSP files? The jar will not be included in your runtime.

Answer (score 18):

Just to improve Sundaraj's findings... disabling TLD scanning completely **will break** JSP/JSTL 
 support.

The issue is that the classpath itself is OK, only Tomcat *additionally* scans the *manifest files* of each Jar, and since with Maven each Jar is in its own directory, that generates meaningless paths (probably running from Eclipse?).

So if you want to keep using JSP with JSTL, you should disable just the manifest scanning.

For Spring Boot 2.0, add this to your application's configuration:

```
  @Bean
  public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
      @Override
      protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
        ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner()).setScanManifest(false);
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: probably why it was necessary for us to add the tld files to the classpath ;)

Comment: @rustyx hello, your solution will break jstl support too, actually - my thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63171429/unable-to-import-taglibs-using-jstl-on-java-11-spring-boot-project)

Comment: Works for me with Spring Boot 2.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

JarScannerFactory [loaded](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/ab35110801998e4f2fa74c62263b0f8030f021d4/java/org/apache/jasper/compiler/JarScannerFactory.java#L42) StandardJarScanner which we need to configure [here](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/ab35110801998e4f2fa74c62263b0f8030f021d4/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/scan/StandardJarScanner.java#L101), so this (for spring boot 2.1.8) works also.

```
import org.apache.tomcat.JarScanner;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class WebContextConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ServletContextInitializer servletContextInitializer() {
        return context -> context.setAttribute(
                JarScanner.class.getName(),
                new StandardJarScanner() {{
                    setScanManifest(false);
                }}
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it working after I add to

**tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip**=\

***.jar**

In **catalina.properties.**