# Disable scanManifest of Jar Scan in tomcat embed in spring boot

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I'm getting some warnings in log, like this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\lowagie\itext\2.0.8\bcmail-jdk14-138.jar (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:60) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:48) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:338) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:288) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) [tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104) [tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:101) [tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5178) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

In a standalone tomcat I can create a `context.xml` with:

```
<Context>
  ...
  <JarScanner scanManifest="false"/>
  ...
</Context>
```

How can I disable the JarScanner for manifest files (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/jar-scanner.html) in a java configuration class using Spring Boot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is controllable via a property now:

```
# Comma-separated list of additional patterns that match jars to ignore for TLD scanning.    
server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=*.jar
```

via [AFTER upgrade from Spring boot 1.2 to 1.5.2, FileNotFoundException during Tomcat 8.5 Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264890/after-upgrade-from-spring-boot-1-2-to-1-5-2-filenotfoundexception-during-tomcat)

Comment: Setting this will break .JSP support as no TLDs will be resolved at all.

Comment: This doesn't break .JSP support. It disables using manifest files to configure additional scanning. You would replace the `*.jar` pattern with the one causing you troubles. For example in my project I use `server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns: jaxb-*.jar`

Comment: How about if I want multiple patterns?

This sort of thing works:
server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=jaxb-api*.jar,txw2*

Comment: Actually this solution turns off scanning for TLD so if you have tag library in the jar it will not be included in your runtime

Comment: @JJRoman what's your alternative solution if i keep TLD scannig for tag library?

Comment: @Aerox actually one above from rustyx worked for me

Comment: Yes, I mean...if you put "false", you always skip every jar, but what if someone want to skip some specific ones? Or maybe the solution is to put the jar at compile time in case you don't need to request it at runtime? maybe that's what is confusing me...

Answer (score 12):

**Edit:** how about this?

```
  @Bean
  public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
      @Override
      protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
        ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner()).setScanManifest(false);
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I have added this line to my Application Class and the warning was gone.

Comment: I get this error `Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to multiple EmbeddedServletContainerFactory beans : tomcatFactory,embeddedServletContainerFactory`. How can I solve it?

Comment: see rustyx answer for Spring Boot 2.X

Answer (score 10):

Just trying to improve Oleg's excellent answer about Spring Boot 1.x..

Here's the corresponding code for Spring Boot 2.0 (Tomcat 8.5):

```
  @Bean
  public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
      @Override
      protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
        ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner()).setScanManifest(false);
      }
    };
  }
```

Just add that to your application's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation to that suggested by [rustyx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485343/rustyx), based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53298008/spring-boot-2-1-0-management-server-port-on-different-port), required as I was customising my actuator management port.

```
@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory containerFactory() {
    return new CustomTomcatServletWebServerFactory();
}

static final class CustomTomcatServletWebServerFactory
    extends TomcatServletWebServerFactory {

    @Override
    protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
        ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner()).setScanManifest(false);
    }

}
```