# Spring boot 2.1.0 management server port on different port

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In my spring boot 2.0 application, I have the main application listening on port 1234, I want to have the management server running on 1235.

So in my config file, I set:

`management.server.port=1235`

My server fails to start, with this error:

> [ERROR] 2018-11-14 05:20:14.958 [main] SpringApplication - Application run failed
>   org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: ServletWebServerFactory implementation com.my.MyApplication$2 cannot be instantiated. To allow a separate management port to be used, a top-level class or static inner class should be used instead
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletManagementContextFactory.determineServletWebServerFactoryClass(ServletManagementContextFactory.java:77) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletManagementContextFactory.registerServletWebServerFactory(ServletManagementContextFactory.java:64) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletManagementContextFactory.createManagementContext(ServletManagementContextFactory.java:52) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration$DifferentManagementContextConfiguration.afterSingletonsInstantiated(ManagementContextAutoConfiguration.java:143) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:863) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
>       at com.my.MyApplication.main(EmsApplication.java:51) [main/:?]

If I remove this:

```
@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory containerFactory() {
    return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void customizeConnector(Connector connector) {
            int maxSize = 50000000;
            super.customizeConnector(connector);
            connector.setMaxPostSize(maxSize);
            connector.setMaxSavePostSize(maxSize);
            if (connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol) {

                ((AbstractHttp11Protocol <?>) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxSwallowSize(maxSize);
            }
        }
        t
    };

}
```

then it works.

How to solve this problem?

thanks!

Comment: The problem doesn't exist if I remove this:

Comment: `ServletWebServerFactory implementation com.my.MyApplication$2` what does that class look like?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe that is the ``TomcatServletWebServerFactory ``.

Comment: Have you tried to define bean `TomcatServletWebServerFactoryCustomizer` and call `addConnectorCustomizers` instead `TomcatServletWebServerFactory`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `TomcatWebServerFactory` sub-class is an anonymous inner-class. It needs to be a static inner-class or a top-level class so that it can be instantiated:

```
@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory containerFactory() {
    return new CustomTomcatServletWebServerFactory();
}

static final class CustomTomcatServletWebServerFactory
        extends TomcatServletWebServerFactory {

    @Override
    protected void customizeConnector(Connector connector) {
        int maxSize = 50000000;
        super.customizeConnector(connector);
        connector.setMaxPostSize(maxSize);
        connector.setMaxSavePostSize(maxSize);
        if (connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol) {
            ((AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>) connector.getProtocolHandler())
                    .setMaxSwallowSize(maxSize);
        }
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you could use a customizer instead of sub-classing `TomcatServletWebServerFactory`:

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> tomcatCustomizer() {
    return (tomcat) -> tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers((connector) -> {
        int maxSize = 50000000;
        connector.setMaxPostSize(maxSize);
        connector.setMaxSavePostSize(maxSize);
        if (connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol) {

            ((AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>) connector.getProtocolHandler())
                    .setMaxSwallowSize(maxSize);
        }
    });
}
```