# Embedded tomcat giving failed to scan jars from classloader hierarchy

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, embedded-tomcat-8

I am newly trying out Embedded tomcat version 8.0.15. Downloaded the maven dependency into my project.

Create the necessary context and instances. Tomcat server is coming up fine. 
But I am getting the below warnings

```
Jun 17, 2017 9:50:44 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner scan 
WARNING: Failed to scan  [file:/C:/Users/raghavender.n/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/xercesImpl.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.FileNotFoundException:C:\Users\raghavender.n\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.2\xercesImpl.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
WARNING: Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/raghavender.n/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/xml-apis.jar] from classloader hierarchy
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\raghavender.n\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.2\xml-apis.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.15</version>
</dependency>
```

How can i disable/avoid the warnings from embedded tomcat jar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not think **xml-apis.jar** is a dependency needed by **tomcat-embed-core** as shown with [dependency hierachy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIrdT.png).

For your error, make sure scope of **xml-apis.jar** is not "**provided**", delete all files under **C:/Users/raghavender.n/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/** and do "**mvn clean install**" then check if **xml-apis.jar** is there.

For Spring Web Application with **Embeded Tomcat** without Spring Boot , you may refer to [this post](http://junjun-java.blogspot.sg/2017/06/spring-with-embedded-tomcat-without.html).

Answer (score 24):

you can add 

  `server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=*.jar`

in `application.properties`file or 

`server:
    tomcat:
        additional-tld-skip-patterns: '*.jar'`

in `application.yml`file.

Refer : [**The Jar Scanner Component**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264890/after-upgrade-from-spring-boot-1-2-to-1-5-2-filenotfoundexception-during-tomcat/43280452#43280452)、[**The official reply**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8810).

Comment: yep server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=*.jar woks, thanks so much

Comment: Beware of https://stackoverflow.com/a/57543800/9004116

Comment: this solution may cover the issues caused by real missing dependency, specified by META-INF\MANIFEST.MF Class-Path property,  so you may avoid wild card like *.jar aka ALL and filter specific jars only. See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/jar-scanner.html

Answer (score 0):

For workaround, in catalina.properties file put the following line:

```
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip=*.jar
```