# Springboot class loading performance from fat jar

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-boot

I have a Springboot application that has an embedded Tomcat to host some Jersey REST service. When I run the fat jar, around 8000 classes load in around 10 minutes. The class loading is extremely slow. However, other java apps seem faster. What should I do to improve the class loading performance from the fat jar? When I run the app with `mvn spring-boot:run`, it's quite fast.

[image]

Comment: So it also takes 10 minutes before the application actually starts to do anything, or is it only the loading of the classes which is spread out over time?

Comment: Hi @Gimby, Yes - the application becomes available only after these 10 minutes. Basically for first 7 minutes or so, it doesn't print anything on the console. Even if I run in -Ddebug mode, the actual autoconfiguration starts much later

Comment: I don't have an explanation for it to be honest, this is highly unusual and not something I can reproduce locally. If it weren't so unlikely I'd be starting to doubt the integrity of the hard drive.

Comment: @Gimby, my hard drive is encrypted and also running Semantec Endpoint Protection. Could it be because of that? The only thing I am not sure of is why `mv spring-boot:run` is so fast - it also scans the jar files - the only difference being a wrapper jar with BOOT-INF

Comment: Get hold of a Java profiler such as YourKit and profile the app to find out what's taking the time. This is honestly the only way you are going to find out exactly what the issue is.

Comment: PS virus checkers are the spawn of the devil when they come across jar files, as these are basically zip files with thousands of entries within them.

You could also try disabling jar scanning if you are using Tomcat:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264890/after-upgrade-from-spring-boot-1-2-to-1-5-2-filenotfoundexception-during-tomcat#43280452

Comment: @Saptarshi Encryption is usually pretty fast and especially when using AES with an AES-NI capable CPU. Reading a RAID with full speed increases the CPU usage by maybe 1% (it used to be 4% without AES-NI). I'd bet on the anti-virus.

Comment: Today [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095448/spring-component-scan-autowire-in-signed-jar-files-is-slow) question was asked. Might it be the same problem?

Comment: @Saptarshi I am facing a similar issue. The fat jar takes approximately 7-8 times as compared to mvn spring-boot:run. Did you find the root cause for this? I also checked the number of times the resolving of resources takes and surprisingly it is equal in both cases. Please do let me know if you could somehow improve the performance. Thanks :)

Comment: @SahilNagpal - For me the same jar was taking only 10-15 seconds in Linux systems. I suspect the problem I faced in Windows system due to the installed Semantec antivirus only. Although it is true that the same Windows system can run other jar files (non-springboot) without such delay in loading. So, I couldn't really find the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

We are pretty sure loading `8,000` classes can never need `10 minutes`.

In one production system, we loaded `70,000` classes in about `65 seconds`.

- Depending on the CPU and System (`Windows` vs `MacOS`), the class loader speed for mass classes could be different
- It is possible in a slower machine it takes `2-3` times slower
- So loaded `70,000` classes may need as worse as `200 seconds` in current hardware (`July 2023`)

Based on the statistics above, load `8,000` classes should need `7` - `22` seconds

So why the Application startup need 10 minutes?

- It must be caused by some other reason
- If you are using Java `8` or later, try to start the application with `JFR`

  - [Monitoring Java Applications with Flight Recorder](https://www.baeldung.com/java-flight-recorder-monitoring)
- Then open the JFR file using [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/)
- Then we can find out exactly the real slowness reason