# Spring Boot: "failed to scan" when spring-boot-starter-tomcat and tomcat-embed-jasper together

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, tomcat

I have a Spring Boot application. It has the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

To process HTML pages, Spring Boot uses Thymeleaf by default. However, I do not like the verbosity of Thymeleaf, which is probably needed to make both the input and output format be HTML, which I do not need at all.

So I chose to use Spring Boot with JSP, as described [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-2-with-jsp-view). It worked very well until I wanted one of the Spring Boot/JSP applications to use a local repository from its parent. It caused `failed to scan: [cannot find some strange non-existing jar from the parent local repository in question]`.

As it turns out, without the dependency on `tomcat-embed-jasper`, the `failed to scan` errors are gone, the parent local repository is used correctly and the application runs fine, with the exception of `.jsp` pages which are no more processes as expected. A browser gets them in their raw form. It is expected because [tomcat-embed-jasper](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-example) processes `.jsp` files.

So I have two excluding choices which prevent the `failed to scan` error:

- do not use the parent's local repo because the mere inclusion of Jasper somehow makes it impossible;
- do not use Spring Boot/JSP but instead SpringBoot/Thymeleaf, so that I do not need to include Jasper.

**Is there a method of having both the repo in question and SpringBoot/JSP?**

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed some issue connected with Jar scanning. I do not understand the details, but anyway, the scan can be limited with JSP/JSTL still possible: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52229296/8564676).