# Spring Boot: Tomcat redirects to HTTPS 8443, no matter which HTTPS port I specify

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, hsts

I use a fairly standard method of redirecting Spring Boot's embedded Tomcat from HTTP to HTTPS, which repeates in a number of tutorials. The method works perfectly for the ports HTTP 8080 and HTTPS 8443, which also repeat as examples in these tutorial. However, changing numbers of these ports to less used values produces a number of problems, as described further.

The method from tutorials is as follows. Application properties:

```
server.http.port=8080
server.http.interface=0.0.0.0

server.port: 8443
server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.key-store: classpath:selfsigned.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password: password
server.ssl.key-store-type: JKS
server.ssl.key-alias: selfsigned
```

Then the configuration of the additional HTTP port:

```
@Component
public class HttpServer {
    @Value("${server.port}") int HTTPS_PORT;
    
    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer(@Value("${server.http.port}") int httpPort) {
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setPort(httpPort);
        connector.setRedirectPort(HTTPS_PORT);
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner()).setScanManifest(false);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
        return tomcat;
    }
}
```

and finally, the configuration of the security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
        http.portMapper()
                .http(Integer.parseInt(Prop.get("server.http.port")))
                .mapsTo(Integer.parseInt(Prop.get("server.port")));
    }
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

The only difference from the tutorials is that I disable scanning of Jar manifest files in `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` because otherwise there are problems if `tomcat-embed-jasper` is included (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43280452/8564676)).

This:

```
server.http.port=8080
server.port: 8443
```

as I said, works perfectly as in the tutorials. This:

```
server.http.port=8080
server.port: 5001
```

redirects still to HTTPS 8443, but there is nothing at 8443, since Tomcat listens at 8080 and 5001:

```
INFO 7360 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 5001 (https) 8080 (http) with context path ''
```

I scanned for `8443` every file in my app, including sources and binaries. There is no single instance of `8443` there. I also used the debugger to verify if the values are correct in `setPort()`, `setRedirectPort()` and `portMapper()`.

This:

```
server.http.port=5000
server.port: 5001
```

produces:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [28/Jan/2021:18:44:46 +0100] "GET /a HTTP/1.1" 302 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [28/Jan/2021:18:44:46 +0100] "GET /a HTTP/1.1" 302 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [28/Jan/2021:18:44:46 +0100] "GET /a HTTP/1.1" 302 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [28/Jan/2021:18:44:46 +0100] "GET /a HTTP/1.1" 302 -
...
```

until the browser complains about too many redirections.

The site is tested on `localhost`, with an invalid certificate, thus Chrome asks for a security exception. Still, Chrome puts the site into HTTP Strict Transport Security, as can be verified at `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`. Can it be, Spring Boot sends something in the HSTS headers which causes the redirection to 8443?

All in all, it seems as if `8080` and `8443` were somewhat special and declared somewhere, possibly in Tomcat or Spring Boot. **How to get rid of these defaults?** **Any way of debugging e.g. the reason behind the redirections? Increase the verbosity of Tomcat, Spring Boot logs?**

**Update 1** To disable HSTS, I modified the security code:

```
    http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity().disable();
```

and removed `localhost` from Chrome' HSTS, but it did not help.

**Update 2** The problem persists when the application is run on an external server with a valid certificate.

Project dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Browsers remember previous permanent redirects, are you sure this is not your case?

Comment: I tested in the incognito mode, with Inspect/Network/Disable cache. I guess that it prevents caching redirections, but I am not sure.

Comment: Did you solve this ? I happen to have the same issue...

Comment: Recently, I ran a parallel (test) server with alternate ports and despite my doubts, it worked. I did not do anything particular in that direction of which I am aware. What changed were mostly the versions: of the operating system, Java machine, Spring Boot, Jasper etc. Of course, might also be that some "rogue" cache expired somewhere but I have no idea what it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not make sense spring team insist to keep use 8443 no matter which port you config. Details see
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8140
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6140